# OpenLayers & Google Maps: TERRAIN not showing as baseMap

Tags: google-maps, layers, google-maps-api, openlayers-2, terrain

I have a problem with OpenLayers and Google maps: on this page:

```
http://***/public/
```

I'm loading Google maps TERRAIN with Openlayers.js, everything worked well for about 1 year, but now the terrain map is not loading as basemap.
I mean, if I try to change layer (using the "tematismi" button on the right and then selecting for example "SAT" and then again "Rilievi"(=Terrain), the Terrain map loads correctly.

I've googled a lot, I thought it was a Google maps update problem, but I still couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use a different version of google-maps-api, for example

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/sodserrw/

The same example with your Google-API address (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
) is also not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/zx4k29k5/

EDIT1:
In the meantime this solution does not work anymore. But the OpenLayers developer updated the OpenLayers.js ( http://dev.openlayers.org/OpenLayers.js ), so it works again with the url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/1juf27oo/

Comment: this solution is not working anymore..

Comment: added update above